# Removing a dictionary element in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove a dictionary element in firebase

[image]

I want to remove the object :-

`D8QmnOSH6vRYiMujKNXngzhdn992: "True"`
at `PendingFriendRequests/RhiZYyMF7STn1vyA27HjnJRsLYb2`
so far i have come up with this :-

```
FIRControllerClass.ref.child("PendingFriendRequests").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(Snapshot) in

                        let dict = Snapshot.value! as! NSMutableDictionary

                        for each in dict {
                        print(each)

                            print(acceptedFriend)

                            if each.key as! String == acceptedFriend{
                                print(each.key)
                                dict.removeObjectForKey(each.key)
                                print(dict)
                                }
                            FIRControllerClass.ref.child("PendingFriendRequests").child(acceptedFriend).setValue(dict)
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: Sounds good. What problem are you having? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#delete_data

Comment: how do i define a path for a dictionary element inside a child?

Comment: `ref.child("PendingFriendRequests/RhiZYyMF7STn1vyA27HjnJRsLYb2/D8QmnOSH6vRYiMujKNXngzhdn992").removeValue()`

Comment: Just a quick Q. (not of the same topic), is it okay to use two backend in the same app? i am using Cloudinary for images that users post and firebase for basic database like userProfile , posts, update...etc

Comment: That's fine.  Storing user data in one place and static content like images in another is very common.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data?authuser=0

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

// Remove the 'capital' field from the document
var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
    capital: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()

FIRControllerClass.ref.child("parentKey").child("childKey").setValue(nil)