# Trying to figure out a better way to delete element from Firestore dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore in my application, and I have a map field called "votes" for user's upvotes or downvotes. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to add an option to delete an element from there, this is what I got now:

```
 //getting the user's votes dictionary and removing the post from it.
    userRef.getDocument { (doc, error) in
        if let _ = error { completion(false) }
        guard let dict = doc?.data()?[USER_VOTES] as? [String: Any] else { return }
        currentDict = dict
        currentDict.removeValue(forKey: id)
    }

    //setting the votes dictionary with the updated one.
    userRef.setData(currentDict) { (error) in
        if let _ = error { completion(false) }
        else { completion(true) }
    }
```

to me, It looks not really efficient, because each time a user is trying to remove an element from this dictionary, I have to write to the database. which can slow down the process and to my understanding, the free tier of Firestore limits the number of writes.
Is there a better way, maybe deleting it right from the user's document? I tried to look for answers, but couldn't find anything that worked for me.
This one for example: [Removing a dictionary element in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466994/removing-a-dictionary-element-in-firebase) looks like what I need to do, but I couldn't get it to work.

EDIT:
I tried deleting it like that

```
    userRef.updateData([
        USER_VOTES:[
            id: FieldValue.delete()
        ]
    ]) { (error) in
        if let _ = error { completion(false) }
    }
```

The app crashes says:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'FieldValue.delete() can only appear at the top level of your update data
```

Comment: Look into use of `FieldValue.delete()` to call out the individual map field to remove.  You'll have to use the field value dot notation to identify the specific field (e.g. "votes.XXX"). https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields

Comment: Btw, this data architecture won't scale well on Firestore because that single document will become too large as your userbase grows. Firestore is optimal when there are many small documents, not the other way around. This is NoSQL in general.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you, Looks exactly like what I wanted!

Comment: @bsod Thanks, I did not think about it. Is there a better way? Im trying to add upvote and downvote option to my app.

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried this, but it didn't work, I could not get to the votes.id to delete it. I tried following the docs but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you tried that didn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited the question. I tried to get to the item I want to delete with it's id. but I get an error.

Comment: It looks like you're not using the dot notation to find the field as I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried but USER_VOTES is a string and I could not do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to delete a specific field you should follow the steps mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data).

For your case I have created the following under collection 'voting':
[image]

So to delete vote2 field you should use:

```
// Get the `FieldValue` object
let FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

// Create a document reference
let fieldRef = db.collection('voting').doc('votes');

// Remove the 'vote2' field from the document 'votes'
let removeField = fieldRef.update({
  vote2: FieldValue.delete()
});
```

And here is the document after running the above:
[image]

**EDIT :**

If the data model is a **map inside a document**, for example:
[image]

Then here is how you can delete a field inside the array which is inside the document:

```
let docRef = db.collection('voting').doc('user1');

let removeField = docRef.set({'votes':
    {['id_vote_1'] : FieldValue.delete()}}, {merge: true});
```

Here is the document after running the above:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but my problem is I have a user document, inside this document I have the votes dictionary. and this solution is not working for me.

Comment: @JohnDoah I have updated my answer showing also how you can delete a field, inside a map which is inside a document.

Comment: Sorry took me few days to respond. This is working now. Thank you very much!